# Vagrant and SmartOS networking

Tags: networking, vagrant, nat, smartos

I am attempting to create a Vagrant (VirtualBox) VM running SmartOS, with the following constraints/requirements:

- The VM should have at least 2 NICs: one that is public-facing (bridged), and one that is private (host-only).
- It is preferable to use static IPs instead of dynamically-allocated ones (at least for the zones, if not the global zone).
- Each zone (to be created) must have 2 vNICs that map to the above NICs.

I have searched the interwebs for a while to find any kind of documentation that would allow me to get this done, but there isn't a lot of support available out there.

I have managed to get to a point where I have the global zone spun up, with an account for the vagrant user (I had to lofs-mount /etc/passwd, /etc/group (for the vagrant group) and /etc/shadow to achieve this). I have 3 nics on my VM:
- NIC 1 (admin nic) is setup as a NAT'd nic in vagrant
- NIC 2 (external nic) is setup as in bridged mode in vagrant
- NIC 3 (internal nic) is setup as a private (host-only in virtualbox terminology) nic in vagrant

Because of the NAT'd admin nic, I have connectivity to the internet in the global zone. But no matter what configuration I try, I cannot get internet connectivity in the zones I create.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Also, feel free to ask me more questions about my configuration so far.

Thanks